# Change a distinct attribute from a group using Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a like system implemented for a page that displays a bunch of user posts. Everything works well, but I'm having trouble getting the image for the like to change after the user presses it. I have a function called likeSystem that fires when a user clicks like:
    (formatted from a returned json array)

```
<img src='img/star.png' id='like"+data.id+"' height='24' 
onClick='likeSystem("+data.id+",1);'/> // 1 indicates type of post.
```

so that all fires and then response data is shot back from the ajax and sent through this.

```
function likeSystem (postid,type) {
  ///working ajax call here.....and then....
  var imagechange = "#like" + postid; 
  if(data==1) 
      {
        //Like successful     
     $(imagechange).attr("src","img/unstar.png");            
      }
   else 
      {
        //unlike successful                
     $(imagechange).attr("src","img/star.png");
      }
```

So the problem I am having is changing the star image into the unstar image and vis versa on the correct post. I tried setting my own variable imagechange which is a combination of like and the postid but it hasn't been working?

Anyone know how to do this correctly?

Comment: shouldn't `if(data==1)` be `if(postid == 1)` ?

Comment: data is the string that comes back from the ajax call. 1 is echoed if it was a like, 2 if it was an unlike.

Comment: the attr calls should be fine. log out your data var. I'd guess its either not getting set correctly, or you're not accessing it correctly. / you might show more code on this interchange...

Answer (score 0):

Got it working 
$("#like" + postid).attr("src","img/unstar.png");